# How to install .Net 8 installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to install .net 8 on VS 2022 Enterprise.

I have updated the VS but I does not appeared. Then I tried to install sdk, it said it is set up correctly, but I cannot use the .net 8 in VS 2022. I tried to but the mark in the allow use previews of .net sdk, but again no succes. I tried to change the environmental variables but that did not help anyway. The VS 2022 still saying that there is not .net 8 installed. How to fix that?

Comment: see https://anthonygiretti.com/2023/06/10/net-8-why-net-8-preview-doesnt-show-up-in-visual-studio-2022/

Comment: Why not just wait 5 days until dotnet 8/VS 2022 17.8 is officially released on November 14th? :)

Answer (score 5):

Please update Visual Studio to version 17.8+. If you still cannot use .net 8, please upgrade the Visual Studio Installer to the latest version. You can use Visual Studio Installer to install .net 8.0 yourself in Individual Components.

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to force .Net 8.0 to appear in the Target framework dropdown?  The SDK is installed, VS 17.8.4 is installed, but no joy.  What's the secret?

Comment: @MC9000 In my Visual Studio, I can switch directly to .net 8.0 in the target framework. If yours doesn't work, please open the Visual Studio Installer to update or repair Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly to reiterate the information on this site. The net8.0 SDK is still in preview so you'll need to do the following.

- Install the latest **preview** of Visual Studio 2022 (17.8)
- If you haven't installed the latest preview, go to Tools > Manage Preview Features. Click on User previews of the .NET SDK (requires restart)

The .NET 8 SDK should now become available.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8.0 is [generally available](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0) now. It looks like Visual Studio 2022 v17.8+ is required to target .NET 8 for a project. Probably you just need to upgrade to the latest VS, since it bundles .NET 8 SDK.

Comment: I figured out the workaround. The problem is that the SDK was not on the same drive as VS2022. I copied both the sdk folder and the sdk-manifest over to the equivalent folders on the other drive. MS has had this problem w/VS users installing it on a drive other than C:

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the **Azure tools** inside Visual Studio for the lastest .Net versions to appear in the New Project dropdown for Azure projects:

Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Azure functions -> Check for updates